# Are ASP.NET's login classes suffiently secure?

Tags: asp.net, security, hash, passwords

I've built a website that uses the login classes that come with ASP.NET (.NET 4) to manage user accounts and passwords.

Are these classes sufficiently secure for a publicly accessable website? What if I were developing a bank's website instead of a stupid custom CMS for a pub?

Update: I didn't know ASP>NET had other login classes. I'm refering to these.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx

Comment: For which ASP.NET login classes are you talking about?

Comment: These ones... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormsAuthentication is widely used and relatively safe if configured properly.

Make sure you add your MachineKey, (you can generate one here http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey which is the same link supplied in the MSDN site)

- If its a secure part of the system; consider setting your session timeouts low (10/15 minutes its convenience vs security).
- Ensure your membership provider is set to a good HASH algorithm i.e. `<membership userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15" hashAlgorithmType="SHA512">`
- and the provider itself is set to hashed rather than encrypted `passwordFormat="Hashed"`
- and that your RoleManager (if your utilizing roles)  and forms authentication section contain the configuration for the cookies; `cookieProtection="All"`

The password reset system in it is a joke; I wont copy and paste myself, but you can see the preferable method of resetting passwords here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213124/combine-passwordrecovery-and-changepassword-control/10237107#10237107

Thats basically a good start; you could also look at Troy Hunts membership security guide http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html

Oh and **Always collect users information / handle logons / and registrations** over HTTPS (SSL). And try to use some sort of verification token (theres one in MVC https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=msdn+AntiForgeryToken), this reduces the attack landscape for CSRF and basically brute forcing.

Comment: Interesting stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are secure enough.. and these can provide you with wide range of functionality like limiting web page views according to the actors and many other things.